# Непонятен механизм работы с фреймами в Javascript

Tags: javascript

файл index.html

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Использование встроенных окон</title>                
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
       function f() {
            var x = frames.content;
            alert(x.res);
        }   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p><a href='javascript:f()'>Click</a></p>
    <iframe src="inner.html" name="content"></iframe>
    <iframe src="new.html" name="two"></iframe>
    <p><a href="javascript:g()">Click2</a></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">     
var x = frames.content; 
        alert(x.res);
</script>
</body>
```

файл inner.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Cодержание внутреннего окна</title>      
    <script type="text/javascript">
         var res = 1000;            
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Вопрос: при вызове через вызов функции(ссылка click) - модальное окно отрабатывает - все выводится, как задумано
При запросе вывода напрямую, без функции - значение `var res` `undefined` 
Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый день! Вероятно, содержимое iframe просто не успевает загрузиться, к тому времени, когда начинает выполняться ваш скрипт. Оберните его во что-нибудь вроде:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var x = frames.content; 
  alert(x.res);
});
```

Или еще как-нибудь добейтесь начала выполнения скрипта после полной загрузки страницы.

Comment: Спасибо. Причина была именно в том, что не успевало загрузиться содержимое iframe

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 var x = frames.content;
 setTimeout('alert(x.res)', 1000);
 </script>

Comment: задержка исполнения в 1 секунду помогла вывести содержимое iframe

Comment: Не самое лучшее решение - ставить задержку в секунду. Представьте, что у пользователя очень очень слабый интернет и контент будет выкачиваться дольше секунды, тогда такая задержка не поможет. Лучше все-таки отталкиваться от факта загрузки. (Протестировать слабый интернет можно установив в консоли разработчика network throttling)